# How to disable button in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have my button binded into my ViewModel with the property of IsEnabled to have it true or false from my ViewModel but it does not make it disabled whenever I set the property binded to false.

My XAML

```
<Button x:Name="buttonSubmit" Margin="20,10,0,0" Height="30" Width="90" Content="Login" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoginEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtPassword}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
public LoginViewModel(ILoginAuth loginAuth)
    {
        this.IsLoginEnabled = true;
        this.LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.LoginUser);
    }

 public async void LoginUser()
    {
            this.IsLoginEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: How did you define the `IsLoginEnabled` property?

Comment: You don't typically bind IsEnabled when you've also bound the Command property. The CanExecute method of the ICommand object controls whether the Button is enabled or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't typically bind `IsEnabled` when you've also bound the `Command` property. The `CanExecute` method of the ICommand object controls whether the Button is enabled or not:

```
public DelegateCommand LoginCommand { get; }
private bool canLogin = true;

public LoginViewModel(ILoginAuth loginAuth)
{
    LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand(LoginUser, () => canLogin);
}

public void LoginUser()
{
    canLogin = false;
    LoginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Comment: No idea which DelegateCommand class you are using, but it should provide a means to set the CanExecute delegate. If you're using Prism, DelegateCommand has a constructor with two arguments: `public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)`. See https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Commands/DelegateCommand.cs

Comment: I got it now. But I'm having an error on p => canLogin which it says that Delegate 'Func<bool>' does not take 1 arguement.

Comment: Ok, please see the edited answer. Use `() => canLogin`.

Comment: You should however use `DelegateCommand<T>` in order to get the CommandParameter passed to the command. In case that's necessary at all.

Comment: I have an issue where after authenticating from an await method, if it fails to authenticate, the button will be just disabled after all.

Comment: Can't tell. However, you shoul not use `async void` except for event handlers. If you change the `canLogin` field, call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` again.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that you're not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel.

Check these links out:

[Explain INotifyPropertyChanged In WPF - MVVM](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-inotifypropertychanged-in-wpf-mvvm/)

[How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface)

You need to implement the interface in order for the ViewModel to inform the View that something has changed and update the UI accordingly.